# (WP 3.0 )Warning: fopen(http://abc.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron)

Tags: wordpress

I've just installed Wordpress 3.0 and I get this error message on the front page:

Warning: fopen(http://abc.com/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in I:\Development\wamp\www\mysite\wp-includes\class-http.php  on line 1045

I'm running WAMP server 2.0i
PHP 5.3.0
Apache 2.2.11

Anyone know what this might be?

Comment: Ran across this ticket that sheds some light on it:  http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/11831

Comment: Good observation! It's exactly my problem (and that I forgot I have debug switch ON). Thanks mate!

Comment: I had this problem on Windows 7 with a WAMP Server configuration.  I edited php.ini by removing the comment from the line 'extension=php_curl.dll' to enable it.  It seems to have fixed the problem.  This solution was listed in the core.trac.wordpress link listed above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pat's comment, this problem is "solved".
In order to set this question to 'Solved', I need to answer my question and later set it to accepted answer...

Comment: I second Pat's answer. For more, here is a pretty good explanation, search for "for masochists" (no pun intended): http://wordpress.org/support/topic/scheduled-posts-still-not-working-in-282

Comment: Yes, Pat's answer was very helpfull. For me the solution was to install curl on the server: sudo apt-get install php5-curl

Comment: Ditto @Jaime, specifically if you are using Ubuntu (in the interest of saving people some time searching - it's at the bottom of that support ticket.)

Answer (score 0):

please check below link for the details answer to fixed above error

http://www.shoutgeek.com/download-failed-could-not-open-handle-for-fopen/